# Pageturn: Duplicate animated objects with time offset (Animation Nodes)

Tags: animation, rigging, animation-nodes

I animated a book page and want to instantiate the page with all its animation. Because the page is modified by several objects like empties and a lattice I don’t know how to do it in an easy way.

I could duplicate the whole collection and shift the keyframes manually, but then I would lose control about it and it would be a lot of work for 100 pages.
I also could instantiate the collection with empties, but then I couldn't shift the animation.

Is it possible to instantiate the rig in animation nodes in a way I can change the animation easily later on?

My scene looks like this right now:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Export basic animation as MDD cache. Then use it with Mesh Cache modifier, it allows offsetting start, even duration. You can find exporting MDD in blender's preferences-> add-on.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a similar thing using shape keys instead of animation keyframes.  Then you can duplicate the object, and build logic to animate the shape keys differentially per object and get time offset programmatically.

In my case, I had a crowd of robots walking and I wanted them to walk at different paces and different parts of the walk cycle.