# How to re-create the folded sheets effect like in the attached images?

Tags: modeling, proportional-editing

I hope this is the right thread for my question. Trying to re-create the "bendy/folded" pages effect. Can you please tell me a few methods on how to achieve this look and feel? i played with the proportional editing, but was wondering if this is the way to go.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, what are you struggling with, shape? material?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: take a look at this question:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156669/pageturn-duplicate-animated-objects-with-time-offset-animation-nodes

The lattice modifier can help you here

Answer (score 0):

Create a plane, subdivide, create a curve, flatten it on Y, put the 2 objects at the same location:

[image]

Give a *Curve* modifier to your plane with the curve as *Curve Object*, move the plane so that it deforms along the curve:

[image]

Duplicate the plane and curve, modify the new curve so the plane deform the way you want:

[image]